# Magento CE 1.9.1.0 - sticky Layered Navigation

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, layered-navigation

I am using the Magento default Layered Navigation on my category pages and I want to make it be sticky, so when you scroll down the page each "shop by" filter will always be visible. So to the code

I added a css style to the sidebar-left class
The style I added is position:fixed;

My issue is when you scroll down the page and get to the bottom the layered navigation goes over the top of the footer. So I am not sure how to change the sidebar-left class (or to create a new class name) that would change the layered navigation to not scroll over the top of the footer.

Answer (score 0):

use `top` and `bottom`. it will not overlap the `footer` and `header`

```
sidebar-left {
    bottom: 296px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 295px;

}
```

Comment: that did not seem to work. it is still overlapping the footer div.

Comment: which theme you are using?

Comment: We are using a theme we purchased off of a template site which has the layered navigation inside a <aside> tag

Comment: increase this `bottom: 296px;`